# Simplest way to make a slightly curved line in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, spline

Currently I'm drawing lines like this:

```
line = d3.svg.line()
svg.append('path')
  .datum([from, to])
  .attr('d', line)
  .attr('class', 'line')
```

Instead of these being perfectly straight, I'd like them to bend slightly. I don't care which direction they bend in.

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this with D3. All the examples seem to be for interpolating a line between a series of values.

Comment: Firstly you should under stand the structure of a path in svg, then may be this https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js

And this: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes

Answer (score 1):

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });


 // Transition links to their new position.
 link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);
```

So really, that's all you need to do, except maybe change the data / diagonal to reflect your case.

The alternative to using the diagonal projection is to just manually build your curve using paths described in Envil's link.